# Add same child object in different parents firebase

Tags: firebase

I am trying to add objects into firebase real time database, so far, i have been creating the same object for different parents. My question is how to save the same object in different parents. So far I am not saving with code, just in firebase console.
Pic to help understand.

[image]

This is the structure `Pais>Belgica>Partidos>2>Estadio` and this stadium is `Spartak Stadium`

[image]

And I want to add the same Stadium that is in `Belgica` into my  `Tunez>Partidos>Estadio>2` with out creating a new Object, is there a way to tell firebase that this object is the same as the on in `Belgica`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create the `Stadium` that is in `Belgica`? Which code do you use? Do you want the copy to the `Tunez>Partidos>Estadio>2` node to be done at the same time?

Comment: I am just creating them on firebase console, i am not using any code. I just want to tell the stadium 2 in tunez that is the same of the Belgica with out creating a new one in tunez.

Comment: Ok. Then Cloud Functions is indeed the way to go. If you are starting with them I would suggest that you have a look at the three following videos from the Firebase team: youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=517s & youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=27s & youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc. And in addition there are some samples from Firebase the team here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

Answer (score 1):

There is no real way to relate something elsewhere in the database to
what you are doing unless you save it yourself in both places.

However, there is another option. Cloud Functions are extremely powerful tools and are fantastic for data consistency. You can take a look at some of the samples Firebase has put out there for just this instance:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I will take a look at it, thanks for the info, i thought there was a way, something like the hash of the object.